# Make a list of class objects from data fetched by an API in python

Tags: python

I am working on a trading bot and i'm finding difficulties in accessing the open, close, high and low price of past timestamps in order to plot them in a candlestick chart. I use Bravado package to make the API call and get the data on the last timestamps. Here's what i have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import bitmex
import json

client = bitmex.bitmex(api_key='',api_secret='')

class candle:
    def __init__(self, open, high, low, close, timeStamp):
         self.open = open
         self.high = high
         self.low = low
         self.close = close
         self.timestamp = timeStamp

def get_candles(timeFrame, symbol, count):
tradeHistory = client.Trade.Trade_getBucketed(binSize=timeFrame, partial=True, symbol=symbol, reverse=True, count=count).result()

   openPrice = tradeHistory[0][0]['open']
   highPrice = tradeHistory[0][0]['high']
   lowPrice = tradeHistory[0][0]['low']
   closePrice = tradeHistory[0][0]['close']
   timeStamp = tradeHistory[0][0]['timestamp']

   c = candle(openPrice, highPrice, lowPrice, closePrice, timeStamp)
   print(c.open)
   print(c.high)
   print(c.low)
   print(c.close)
   print(c.timestamp)


#def new_order(symbol, orderQty, ordType, price):

get_candles('5m', 'XBTUSD', count=10)
```

The variable count dictates the number of timestamps to be collected. I want to be able to make each one of these timestamps a class candle object in order to perform statistical analysis.

EDIT: here is the result of the API call (print(tradeHistory)):

```
([{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 35, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11122.5, 'high': 11125.0, 'low': 11050.0, 'close': 11123.0, 'trades': 166, 'volume': 907181, 'vwap': 11097.5474, 'lastSize': 1, 'turnover': 8175270370, 'homeNotional': 81.7527037, 'foreignNotional': 907181.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 30, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11116.5, 'high': 11122.5, 'low': 11050.0, 'close': 11122.5, 'trades': 120, 'volume': 1103521, 'vwap': 11090.163, 'lastSize': 6567, 'turnover': 9951416522, 'homeNotional': 99.51416522, 'foreignNotional': 1103521.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 25, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11120.0, 'high': 11120.0, 'low': 11050.0, 'close': 11116.5, 'trades': 147, 'volume': 429630, 'vwap': 11100.0111, 'lastSize': 50, 'turnover': 3870675270, 'homeNotional': 38.7067527, 'foreignNotional': 429630.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 20, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11106.0, 'high': 11122.5, 'low': 11078.5, 'close': 11120.0, 'trades': 32, 'volume': 112854, 'vwap': 11119.7598, 'lastSize': 2, 'turnover': 1014989360, 'homeNotional': 10.1498936, 'foreignNotional': 112854.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 15, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11119.5, 'high': 11122.5, 'low': 11106.0, 'close': 11106.0, 'trades': 36, 'volume': 63884, 'vwap': 11122.2333, 'lastSize': 2, 'turnover': 574410700, 'homeNotional': 5.744107, 'foreignNotional': 63884.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 10, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11094.0, 'high': 11119.5, 'low': 11064.0, 'close': 11119.5, 'trades': 59, 'volume': 67005, 'vwap': 11103.7086, 'lastSize': 6438, 'turnover': 603476539, 'homeNotional': 6.0347653900000005, 'foreignNotional': 67005.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 5, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11075.5, 'high': 11126.5, 'low': 11053.0, 'close': 11094.0, 'trades': 69, 'volume': 117567, 'vwap': 11080.3324, 'lastSize': 10030, 'turnover': 1061135068, 'homeNotional': 10.611350680000001, 'foreignNotional': 117567.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 18, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11063.5, 'high': 11075.5, 'low': 11064.0, 'close': 11075.5, 'trades': 14, 'volume': 7335, 'vwap': 11072.9709, 'lastSize': 2000, 'turnover': 66249407, 'homeNotional': 0.66249407, 'foreignNotional': 7335.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 17, 55, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11078.0, 'high': 11121.0, 'low': 10900.0, 'close': 11063.5, 'trades': 148, 'volume': 5419673, 'vwap': 10961.3066, 'lastSize': 2, 'turnover': 49448358082, 'homeNotional': 494.4835808199999, 'foreignNotional': 5419673.0}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 17, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'open': 11082.5, 'high': 11149.5, 'low': 11052.5, 'close': 11078.0, 'trades': 81, 'volume': 3389036, 'vwap': 11101.2433, 'lastSize': 2, 'turnover': 30529671667, 'homeNotional': 305.29671666999997, 'foreignNotional': 3389036.0}], <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x7fe1509d7c18>
```

Comment: You want to build a `candle` object for each entry in `tradeHistory[0]` and save those in a list?

Comment: yeah i think that'll do it

Comment: I was going to post an answer very similar to the one @sadmicrowave did. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me post what my solution would be, then I'll talk about the changes below:

```
class Candle:
    def __init__(self, open, high, low, close, timeStamp):
         self.open = open
         self.high = high
         self.low = low
         self.close = close
         self.timestamp = timeStamp

   def __str__ (self):
        return """
        Open: %s
        High: %s
        Low: %s
        Close: %s
        Timestamp: %s""" % (self.open, self.high, self.low, self.close, self.timestamp)

class GatherCandles :

    trades = []

    def __init__ (self, timeFrame, symbol, count):
       self.client = bitmex.bitmex(api_key='',api_secret='')
       self.tradeHistory = self.getTradeHistory(timeFrame, symbol, count)
       self.constructTrades(self.tradeHistory[0])

    def getTradeHistory (self, timeFrame, symbol, count):
         """Get the trade history from the API"""

         return self.client.Trade.Trade_getBucketed(binSize=timeFrame, partial=True, symbol=symbol, reverse=True, count=count).result()

    def constructTrades (self, th):
        """Iterate through list of trade history items"""

        for trade in th :
             # You can do something here with your `trade` data if you desire...
             self.trades.append( Candle(trade['open'], trade['high'], trade['low'], trade['close'], trade['timestamp']) )

    def printTrades (self):
        """Loop through all trades gathered and instantiated as `Candle` and print properties of each Candle object"""
        [print(t) for t in self.trades]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = GatherCandles('5m', 'XBTUSD', count=10)

    for trade in g.trades :
        # do something here on the properties of trade.  Like: trade.open < trade.high
        print( trade.open )
        print( trade.high )

    g.print_trades()
```

First, it is good practice to name classes with an upper-case character (i.e. `Candle`).  This way, whenever you see a reference to `Candle(...)` you know it is new class instantiation syntax, instead of `candle(...)` which looks like you are calling a function.

Next, overwriting `__str__` for a class gives you access to changing how the class prints itself when calling `print( c )` (assuming `c` is your instantiated class).

Next, I recommend making another class to handle all your `get candle` functions and actions.  It is easier to interact with an object versus procedural code that is floating around without a structure.

Comment: thanks! i think this will do it. i just didnt understand why do you create the api client inside GatherCandles

Comment: `GatherCandles` is where you make the API call to get the data, so why not contain all API functionality within the same scope?  This way, you don't have some of your API functionality floating around your script already initialized, and some within a class waiting to be used; keeping things properly organized is a very important aspect to becoming a proficient programmer.

Comment: What if i want to execute orders  ? do i need to create another api client inside the class? can't i just create a client on main and pass it as argument to the GatherCandles class?

Comment: if you have other actions you want to use the API client for, then rename `GatherCandles` to something more fitting like `BitmexWrapper` and then use that class to house all your methods you want to execute against the `bitmex` site

Comment: ok got it. another thing, i am getting this error and i don't know why: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sketch.py", line 55, in <module>
    g = GatherCandles(client, '5m', 'XBTUSD', count=10)
  File "sketch.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.constructTrades(tradeHistory)
NameError: name 'tradeHistory' is not defined

Comment: tradeHistory is correctly defined so i really dont get whats wrong

Comment: sorry, change the line `self.constructTrades(tradeHistory)` to `self.constructTrades(self.tradeHistory)` I made the correction in my post above.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. but now i'm having this error:   File "sketch.py", line 46, in constructTrades
    t = trade[0]
TypeError: 'RequestsResponseAdapter' object does not support indexing, how can i fix this?

Comment: also, where is the attribute 'trade' defined?

Comment: So, this is where my comment is in the code explaining that you may have to tweak this loop to fit how the data is brought back from the API call.  Can you print out the results of the API call in your original post as an edit and I can see how it is structured?  `trade` is defined in the for loop declaration: `for trade in th:` means each element in the `th` list will get looped over and named `trade` so you can interact with each element.

Comment: @JonDoe I just updated my code to work after testing with you API return data.  You'll need to change a few things as well.  Including the `__str__` method inside the `Candle` class, and the `constructTrades` method inside the `GatherCandles` class.  I also removed the `__str__` reference in `GatherCandles` and replaced with a printing method called `printTrades`

Comment: now im getting this error message: File "sketch.py", line 43, in constructTrades
    self.trades.append(Candle(trade['open'], trade['high'], trade['low'], trade['close'], trade['timestamp']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: run this for me and paste the output: `print( type(tradeHistory) )`.  Based on your edit and addition of the output of tradeHistory, I thought it would be in `list` form.  But it may be in a different form that we must convert to a list

Comment: this is the ouput: <class 'tuple'>

Comment: What about `print( type( tradeHistory[0] ) )`

Comment: : <class 'list'>

Comment: ok, thats what I thought.  I was able to replicate the issue.  Your API results pasted in your post above are incomplete.  You are missing a closing parenthesis; which threw off my testing and I needed to improvise.  Anyway, the results are being returned as a tuple and the second position in the tuple is an object reference, so you only want the first tuple position.  As such change `self.constructTrades(self.tradeHistory)` to `self.constructTrades(self.tradeHistory[0])`

Comment: that works, but how can i access each object individually?

Comment: It depends when you want to access the `Candle` data.  You can access the data while you are in the `for` loop in `constructTrades`; or you can access it outside of your classes after the `g = GatherCandles(...)` reference in another `for` loop.  See my post for an example of each...

Comment: what i want to do is to sed all the separate candles in the list  from older to newest to an R instance for it to apply statistics on this data. when i automate the data aquisition process (near real time) i will want to fetch the newest candle and add to to the R instance. just like a chart

Comment: So, I have to ask, why are you doing all this in python if it needs to be used by R?  R has built-in methods to access API endpoints and gather and iterate over the results, just like python does.  It seems like you are adding an extra step and an extra layer of complexity

Comment: Beyond that, I think we've exhausted the use of comments on this post.  If you want to know how to pass a list of objects from Python to R, I would read up on that process, or post a new question.

Comment: I found it easier to connect to an API rather than R and as far as im concerned, R is not good to make post requests to an api